# Android: how appcompat and material create appcompat and material views from default?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-components-android

When you make layouts in Android, you could make default views like TextView or ImageView. But when you use appcompat or material library, they automatically map these views to appcompat or material views. So my question is how they do that, and how I could do that?

For example I have custom MyTextView, and I want all TextView views to be mapped to MyTextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is some stuff that your activity (extended from AppCompatActivity) is doing under the hood.

Basically, it looks like this:

1. Activity calls [`setFactory2`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater#setFactory2(android.view.LayoutInflater.Factory2)) method of the default `layoutInflator` with custom implementation of `LayoutInflator.Factory2` interface.
2. This implementation passes all the `createView` calls to the instance of [AppCompatViewInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatViewInflater) class.
3. `AppCompatViewInflater` checks the names of the views it needs to create, and creates AppCompat views instead of default ones, if there are any.

For Material it's the same story, but with MaterialComponentsViewInflater instead of AppCompatViewInflater.

You can make your own CustomViewInflater by extending from AppCompatViewInflater (or material), and put this line with the path to your inflater in your app theme:

```
<item name="viewInflaterClass">your.app.package.CustomViewInflater</item>
```